# verilog code of rns subtraction

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

i try to write the verilog code for rns subtraction in which i used to perform modulo operation. in given below code i take input   sum80 = 6'd4
           sum81 = 6'd6
           sum30 = 6'd1
           sum31 = 6'd4
           sum71 = 6'd2
          sum70 = 6'd3
          sum50 = 6'd2
          sum51 = 6'd1

but according to this rad71= -1 and rad51= -1, but after simulation it gives rad71=rad51=1111111 which is alright but in output sum7x should be equal to( sum7x=6) and (sum5x=4) but i am getting (sum5x=0000110) and (sum7x=0001000)

i want it should consider rad71=rad51= -1 and  sum5x= m5(7'd5)-rad51=4....how to get this.....what changes should i made in our code

```
module mod_sub1(clk,rst,sum80,sum81,sum30,sum31,sum71,sum70,sum50,sum51,sum8x,sum3x,sum5x,sum7x,rad81,rad31,rad51,rad71);

parameter m3=6'b000011,m5=6'b000101,m7=6'b000111,m=13'd840,m8=6'b001000;
input clk;
input rst;
input [5:0] sum80,sum81,sum30,sum31,sum71,sum70,sum50,sum51;
output reg signed  [6:0] sum8x,sum3x,sum5x,sum7x;
 output reg  signed [6:0] rad81,rad31,rad51,rad71;


always@(posedge clk )
 begin
   rad81=sum81-sum80;
    if (rad81<0)
      sum8x=(m8-rad81);
     else 
      sum8x=rad81;
  end

 always@(posedge clk )
 begin
    rad31=sum31-sum30;
      if (rad81<0)
      sum3x=(m3-rad31);
     else 
      sum3x=rad31;
  end

   always@(posedge clk )
 begin
  rad71=sum71-sum70;
    if (rad71<0)
      sum7x=(m7-rad71);
     else 
      sum7x=rad71;
  end


 always@(posedge clk )
 begin
  rad51=sum51-sum50;
  if (rad51<0)
      sum5x=(m5-rad51);
     else 
      sum5x=rad51;
  end



endmodule
```

Comment: Should the inputs not be signed?

Comment: @Morgan Sir i think there is no need for signed inputs...as we are checking rad81,rad31...so on.

Comment: I do not understand 'as we are checking'. You have `rad81=sum81-sum80` and `sum8x=rad81;` where the LHS is signed and the RHS unsigned. If the inputs hold signed values they should be declared as signed, if not then `sum8x=rad81;` will not work as a large positive number will become a negative number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(rad31 mod 3) is rad31 +(-) 3, not 3 - rad31

Comment: can you explain how you got the answer that you got.  what is the logic behind it

Comment: "logic behind it" is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic. When you want modulo of something, you add or subtract modulus until getting value in range ( 0, modulus-1 )